# How can I merge multiple individual worksheets in an Excel workbook that are in the same format (but different lengths)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, lookup, splunk

I have an inherited (and sometimes still-updated) workbook with many worksheets (currently 50+).

Each of these tabs has a table in the format of:

```
segment_name | subsegment | subnet       | ipaddress
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ASD          | ASD-FGH    | 10.10.10     | 10.10.10.17-40
             | ASD-JKL    | 192.168.100  | 192.168.100.50-200
```

Cells `A1` through `D1` are always named the same thing on each tab, always in the same order

`A2` is a merged cell the height of the whole table (not all are the same height)

`A2` is also the same name as the tab/worksheet name (eg ASD, DFG, GHJ, etc)

If this was a one-off, I'd manually copy/paste the content of each tab's table into a new worksheet, unmerge the merged cells, [filldown](https://www.lifewire.com/excel-fill-down-command-3124068) the empty spaces, and move on with my life

However, since the source workbook *does* get updated/changed periodically (new IPs/IP ranges added, removed, etc), I need a way to rebuild the simplified format (which is ultimately being converted into a CSV [lookup](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/Aboutlookupsandfieldactions) table for Splunk) from the source on-demand

I *presume* there's a clever (or even not-so-clever) way to do this with an Excel [macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/quick-start-create-a-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8)/[VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications). However, I'm not sure how to go about it.

The logic should look something like this:

```
create tempsheet
foreach worksheet as currentsheet
    if currentsheet.A1="segment_name"
        append all rows from currentsheet.B -> currentsheet.last-populated to the end of tempsheet
    else
       advance to next worksheet
```

How would this *actually* look in VBA?

Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: While not a *full* solution, I found https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2972-excel-save-export-convert-multiple-all-sheets-to-csv-text.html which may lead to an interim (ie multi-step) solution

Comment: perhaps using data connections?

Comment: @gns100 - what is a "data connection"?

Comment: click on the menu item `Data` menu, the far left item should be `get and transform data` (previously known as powerQuery). you can use that to connect all of your workbooks into one new workbook.